# ASP .NET on Websphere

Tags: asp.net, websphere

Good day. I just want to consult about using websphere as san application server for .NET (ASP). Our company uses it because of an application made from JAVA (JSP) and i am working on a new application using ASP. Is it possible for websphere to accomodate ASP? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not natively, but Mainsoft has a [product](http://dev.mainsoft.com/Default.aspx?tabid=223) that may assist you

Mainsoft®, Portal Edition, enables you to use your expertise in Visual Studio® development and the C#/Visual Basic languages to create portlets that run natively on IBM WebSphere® Portal and integrate tightly with the Java stack of the portal server itself.

Comment: The download appears to be: http://dev.mainsoft.com/Default.aspx?tabid=177 - it does say : Development and runtime licenses are now available free-of-charge, without restrictions in regards to CPUs or commercial use.

Comment: who knows. it's certainly free to click the link he found you.

Comment: i just want to make sure that it's worth the download.